# synchronizing windows phone 8 app to a table in the sql server database

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-2012

I want my windows phone 8 application to sync automatically, when a row is inserted in a table.

That is, a xaml page in my app displays all the data in a table.

1. So, if a new row is added to that table, the change should be updated in my app too.(while app is running)
2. If the app is closed, it has to show notification( kind of).

I have no idea how to do it, and googled it. I came across Change Tracking, etc, but still couldn't to do it.!

Give me some solution.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you need to be able to download table data from server. You will need to create a webservice that will serve tabla data and a service client in your WP8 application that will consume the data.
2. Second, you have to understand **push notification** concept on Windows Phone. Google for it. I recommend  you to practice it a bit: create a single button WPF app, that sends a push notification a updates you app tile on WP8.
3. For updating your windows phone when a record is created on server:
   Cant you just create a windows service, that periodically makes a request to DB to check any new records since last check? If there are new records it will send a notification to your WP8 app. When WP8 App recieves a notification it will update its tile, or if app is running, it will download new data from server.

alternative solution is, that you create a webservice with Insert method that will insert a row to you table on server. In the same method you will send a notifications to all your wp8 clients.

There are various solutions for this kind of app. It depends on your scenario. Can you describe your app?